# Retrieve the full page HTML - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve the full HTML of a page, so far I am using:

`$('*').html()`

Is there a better way (also this excludes the `<html>` tags at the top)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried `$('html').html()` but this of course excludes the html element.

`$('html').parent().html()` didn't work either because the root has no parents.

`$(document).html()` also fails

You could get the contents and then capture any attributes from the html element that you require, at leas then you can rebuild it if needed

Edit based on comment:
Just found this cross browser OuterHTML plugin
http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

Comment: +1 I tried various approaches, including outerHTML but that isnt a standard.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're using this for, but would using `$.get` to fetch the `location.href` be a reasonable workaround (as a bonus you'd get the DOCTYPE and other header-ish stuff as well).

```
$.get(location.href, function(html) {
    alert(html);
});
```

Ok maybe that's kinda silly...

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetPageHtml()
{
   return $('html')[0] + $('html').html() + '</html>';
}
```

Comment: but what about potential attributes of the HTML tag?

Comment: @T. Stone: nice catch. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

`html =  $('<dummy>').append($('html').clone()).remove().html();`